# C++ compilation issue

Tags: c++

I am seeing some C++ errors I don't understand  (I am java centric coder):

```
WarningNotification_if.cpp: In function 'void fireStatusBarMessage(char*, int)':
WarningNotification_if.cpp:62:14: error: expected type-specifier
WarningNotification_if.cpp:62:14: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'WarningEventData*' in initialization
WarningNotification_if.cpp:62:14: error: expected ',' or ';'
```

Here is the actual code:

```
void fireStatusBarMessage(char *message = 0, int aTime = 0 )
{
   LmLocker locker( (char *)__FILE__, __LINE__, &WarningEventUpdateMutex );
   HMI_DEBUG(EVENT_DEBUG, (stderr, "Fire Status Bar Message\n") );
   if ( message != 0 )
   {
      QString warningMessage = QString( message );
      WarningEventData *theEventData = 
         new WarningEventData::WarningEventData();
      theEventData->initialize();
      theEventData->setMessageType( SESSION_STATUSBAR_TYPE );
      theEventData->setCommand( APPEND_WARNING );
      theEventData->setMessage( warningMessage );
      theEventData->setModifier( aTime );
      theEventData->setCategory( SESSION_STATUSBAR_TYPE );
      WarningNotification::fireChange( SESSION_STATUSBAR_TYPE, theEventData );
   } /* endif - message contents */
}
```

Do I need to be importing something else or using a certain -D flag?

Comment: Which line of the code is line 62?

Comment: "CPP" (from your title) is the C preprocessor.  Is that what you meant to ask about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> WarningEventData *theEventData = 
>      new WarningEventData::WarningEventData();
> ```

This is quite odd.  A `new` expression is supposed to name a type, not a constructor.  Is `WarningEventData` inside a like-named namespace?  And if so, why isn't it `WarningEventData::WarningEventData* theEventData` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
WarningEventData *theEventData = new WarningEventData::WarningEventData();
                                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Is WarningEventData is a namespace ?
```

If so, then you have to instantiate like -

```
WarningEventData::WarningEventData *theEventData = 
     new WarningEventData::WarningEventData();
```

If there is no namespace involved at all -

```
WarningEventData *theEventData = new WarningEventData();
```

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I did c++, but I believe the constructor does not expect an explicit call.  Try replacing

```
WarningEventData *theEventData = new WarningEventData::WarningEventData();
```

with

```
WarningEventData *theEventData = new WarningEventData();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to include the file with the declaration of WarningEventData, as with

```
#include "WarningEventData.h"
```